# Wrong Create Value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I got confused about inserting the values into my table:

[image]

This is my user_idea table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_idea` (
  `idea_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `innovators` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idea_categories` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idea_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `innovators` (`innovators`),
  KEY `idea_categories` (`idea_categories`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

ALTER TABLE `user_idea`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `innovators` FOREIGN KEY (`innovators`) REFERENCES `user_info` (`id`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `idea_categories` FOREIGN KEY (`idea_categories`) REFERENCES `idea_categories` (`category_id`);
```

I want to have a result like this

[image]

Comment: Hey, no images please. Edit your question and add your code here instead, and any error messages.

Comment: The foreign key must references a single value in the target table, not multiple, but you try to link using a comma-separated list of two values, so no wonder it's not working... If you need a one-to-many relationship, then search for how to create one, using a linking table.

Comment: Hi @andreas, youare inserting value 'Jack' into column user_id in your table user_idea. I am sure that in your table user info there is no user with ID = Jack. There can be a user with name Jack but you need find out his ID and insert that ID instead of value Jack. If you have ID's in your table user_info organized in a way that the alues in the ID column are something like Jack, Peter or simmilar then this is not a good way.

Comment: @VBoka The `user_id` does seem to be text, not an integer, so that is probably not the problem.